# Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.InvalidPageLayoutException after moving site collection

Tags: 2013, content-database

I have two web application:

- `http://old.corp.com`
- `http://new.corp.com`

I had a site collection on `http://old.corp.com/path/1`. The site collection was in a dedicated content database and is based on a publishing site.

I "moved" the site collection my dismounting and mounting the DB:

```
Dismout-SPContentDatabase wss_content_my
mount-spcontentdatabase wss_content_my -webapplication http://new.corp.com
```

After the move however, on *some* pages, I get weird errors stating the page layouts is invalid : `Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.InvalidPageLayoutException`

A dive into the ULS logs shows :

> Normalization for URL http://old.corp.com/path/1/_catalogs/masterpage/somelayout.aspx failed. Unknown foreign URL.

As you can see, the old url is still referenced in some page files.

Using SP Manager or powershell confirms it:

`$file.Properties["PublishingPageLayout"]` outputs : `http://old.corp.com/path/1/_catalogs/masterpage/somelayout.aspx, My page layout`

How can I fix my issue?

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, I ended up by scripting the fix:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.POwershell

$web = Get-SPWeb http://new.corp.com/path/1

$ctid = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeID]"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2"


$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteDataQuery
$query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate='850' />";
$query.Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection' />";
$query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='PublishingPageLayout' Type='URL'/>";
$query.RowLimit = [int]::MaxValue
$allPages = $web.GetSiteData($query)



$allPages.Rows.Count

$site = $web.Site
foreach($pageInfo in $allPages){
    $subweb = $site.OpenWeb([guid]$pageInfo.WebId)

    $list = $subWeb.Lists[[guid]$pageInfo.ListId]

    $page = $list.GetItemById($pageInfo.ID)
    $prop = $page.Properties["PublishingPageLayout"]

    if(-not $prop.StartsWith($site.Url) -and -not $prop.StartsWith("/")) {

        $uri = New-Object uri($prop)

        $newprop = $prop.Replace($uri.Scheme + "://" + $uri.Authority, "")

        $page.Properties["PublishingPageLayout"]= $newprop
        $page.SystemUpdate()
        $prop = $newprop
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Updated $($page.File.ServerRelativeUrl) from $prop to $newProp"
    }
    if($prop.StartsWith("/_catalogs")) {


        $newprop = "/path/1" + $prop

        $page.Properties["PublishingPageLayout"]= $newprop
        $page.SystemUpdate()
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Updated $($page.File.ServerRelativeUrl) from $prop to $newProp"
    }


    $subWeb.Dispose()

}
```

Actually, I had to deal with two cases:

- wrong absolute url: in this case, I removed the protocol and hostname in the url
- wrong relative url: I relocated some urls from web app's root site relative url to actual managed path url

Answer (score 1):

I am guesing you need to refresh the site collection.

```
$db = Get-SPDatabase | where {$_.Name -eq "DatabaseName"}
$db.RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase()
```

[Refresh Site Collections in Config Database](http://sharepointredneck.blogspot.com/2012/06/refresh-site-collections-in-config.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is still present

Comment: couple of things to check...did you hardcoded the url in the site collection some where? also try to detach the content db and wait for couple of min then re attach it....